# Create a buffer programmatically to store file from raw or asset?

Tags: android, buffer, android-resources

I have searched some of article about read/write file in raw, and the answer is not possible, now I am thinking to create a buffer programmatically to store the file from raw or asset, then i can  access it dynamically, how is possible to make it true?

Comment: What is the question? If you have a file in raw or assets folder you can access it, if you want more control, just write the contents into another file on SD?

Comment: i wanna rewrite the origin file...like updateing file, and it's accessable!!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard) should get you started